# How to get -std=c++11 w/ libstdc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libstdc++, libc++

Why doesn't this work:

```
#include <regex>
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled as:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ temp.cpp
temp.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'regex' file not found
#include <regex>
         ^
1 error generated.


clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

If I allow `stdlib` to be `libc++` then it compiles. Regex is `c++11`, but `clang` doesn't seem to have a problem with both `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++` per se. On my machine at least, it looks like there's something I could use in `/usr/include/regex.h`, but that's not standard, and besides there are things other than regex I'd like to use (e.g. std::to_string).

The reason this has come up is because I'd like to link to a 3rd party library (for which I don't have the source) which is complied as `std::string` and not `std::__1::basic_string`, but my code uses `std::regex` and `std::to_string`. I'm not sure I want to introduce a dependency on boost.

Comment: Maybe your libstc++ isn't C++11 compliant?

Comment: I'm OSX 10.10.5, so I'd think Apple would be on task...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15853893/3425536) might help.

Comment: `<regex>` was not properly functional in libstdc++ until the version that shipped with gcc-4.9, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/241631). Maybe you have an older version.

Comment: clang has it's own stdlib, may be you can use it?

Comment: @SergeyA can you clarify? I'd guess that's what it's already using.

Comment: I believe, what you are using is a gnu standard library. Clang has it's own, `libc++`.

Comment: @SergeyA right, but libc++ is not binary compatible with the 3rd party library I want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple ships a very old version of libstdc++ with OS X (4.2.1 I think).  That version did not fully support C++11, so you'll need to get a newer version to use `std::regex`.

Comment: If `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++` are mutually exclusive, IMHO, there should a warning!

Comment: They aren't technically mutually exclusive, even with the version shipped by default.  libstdc++ 4.2.1 does support some C++11 features that had been proposed at the time it released (mid 2007).

Comment: I suppose this SO question can serve as the warning! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The version of libstdc++ shipped with OS X comes from gcc-4.2.1, the last version of GCC before FSF decided to adopt GPL3.  Apple deprecated libstdc++ in OS X Lion in favor of libc++ from the LLVM Project.  If you want to use C++11 on OS X, you should be using `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`